# Why does my javascript code not not pass on the value from one div to another?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to take the value from one div and display it in another.

Here is the relevant html code:

```
<div id="main">
    hello
</div>
```

The following is the function I have, which should take the number from the div I click on and display it in the div with the id 'main'.

```
function clr(e) {
  var clickedElement = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
  var currentXValue = clickedElement.innerHTML;    

  document.body.getElementById('main').innerHTML = currentXValue;
}
```

For some reason, the final line in the function does not do what I intend it to.

Comment: You may wish to put this into jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```js
function clr(e) {
  var clickedElement = document.getElementById(e.id);
  var currentXValue = clickedElement.innerHTML;    

  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = currentXValue;// it should be document.getElementById not document.body
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
   Hello
  </div>

<button onclick="clr(this)" id="Foo">Foo</button>
```

Comment: simple and beautiful that is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please change `document.body.getElementById('main').innerHTML` to `document.getElementById('main').innerHTML` and it should work fine.

Comment: you're correct, Arpit pointed that out as well. Silly newbie mistakes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using Jquery.

```
$('div').click(function () {
  $('#main').html($(this).html());
});
```

Here is a Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yuykhynm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/hidoos/Lpz917vo/

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">heello</div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

and JS

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
    result = document.getElementById('result');

outer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var html = '';
  if (e.target === outer && e.currentTarget === outer) {
    html += '<p>Outer element was clicked directly - it is <code>e.target</code> <em>and</em> <code>e.currentTarget</code>.</p>';
  }

  if (e.target !== outer && e.currentTarget === outer) {
    html += '<p>Outer element is the current target, but it was not clicked directly - it is <code>e.currentTarget</code>.</p>';
  }

  html += [
    '<ul>',
      '<li><code>e.target === &lt;div id="', e.target.id, '"&gt;</code></li>',
      '<li><code>e.currentTarget === &lt;div id="', e.currentTarget.id, '"&gt;</code></li>',
       '<li><code>e.currentTarget === &lt;div id="', e.currentTarget.innerHTML, '"&gt;</code></li>',
    '</ul>'
  ].join('');

  result.innerHTML = html;

});
```

u can add innerhtml